# How do I check if my OpenPGP key is in the Ubuntu keyserver?

Tags: gnupg

I'm in the process of adding my OpenPGP key to Launchpad and I just uploaded it to Ubuntu's keyserver. Now I can only continue once the key is available through the keyserver. Is there a way to check if that's already the case?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Command line way:

- Run:

  ```
    gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --search-key 'your@mail.com'
  ```

Graphical way:

- Run `seahorse` (*Passwords and Encryption Keys*), hit the *Find Remote Keys...* button, enter your key ID in the search field, and finally only select the Ubuntu keyserver:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check only by `keyIDs`:

> `gpg -i --batch --keyserver <keyserver> --recv-keys <keyIDs>`

```
--keyserver <keyserver> => This is the server that gpg communicates with to receive keys, send keys, and search for keys
--recv-keys <keyIDs>    => Import the keys with the given keyIDs from a keyserver.
--batch                 => Don’t invoke a pinentry or do any other thing requiring human interaction.
-i                      => Asks before importing key.
```