# How do I publish a GPG Key?

Tags: gnupg

This link works for Ubuntu 10 https://launchpad.net/+help-registry/openpgp-keys.html#publish
How can I do this in Ubuntu 12.10 because its different in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Can you please mention what you've done already and what makes you think there is a difference? That should help the community provide targeted answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the command-line to publish your key you can run,

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys yourkeyID
```

and then you should get the following notification:

```
gpg: sending key yourkeyID to hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

You can check it is present on the server by running the command given in this article:

- [How do I check if my OpenPGP key is in the Ubuntu keyserver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29889/how-do-i-check-if-my-openpgp-key-is-in-the-ubuntu-keyserver)

You can also use the gui program, `Seahorse`, to manage your keys, which is the 'Passwords and Encryption Keys' program mentioned in the link you quoted, although you might have to install it now.

A more recent gpg tutorial is available at [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto), which goes through in some detail how to create, publish, and backup your GPG keys.

Comment: **yourkeyID** can be fetch with `gpg --list-keys`

Comment: Would it be possible to verify that is my gpg key already published?